# Understanding the SHA1 sunset on SSL

Tags: security-certificate, google-chrome

According to this article: http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html

SHA1 in SSL certificates will start reporting SSL errors to chrome browsers fairly soon. If SHA1 is still a part of your SSL chain, what expiration date range will continue to be error free for a certificate after the chrome SHA1 updates are fully released?

Comment: All web browsers have announced to quit their support for SHA-1 encrypted website. But I've found many website such as Google, Facebook, LinkedIn are encrypted with old and less secured SHA-1 algorithm. Now I have question in my mind whether migration from SHA-1 to SHA-2 is required or not... https://shachecker.com/check/Facebook.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the phaseout is based on the post-2016 expiration date of the SHA-1. This mostly deals with certs that have been registered for a period beyond 2015. According to the way they are wording this, certs expiring in 2014/2015 *should* be ok and won't flag warning. According to Digicert:

- November 2014 - SHA-1 SSL Certificates expiring any time in 2017 will show a warning in Chrome.
- December 2014 - SHA-1 SSL Certificates expiring after June 1, 2016 will show a warning in Chrome.
- January 2015 - SHA-1 SSL Certificates expiring any time in 2016 will show a warning in Chrome.

More info from: [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/sha-2-ssl-certificates.htm) | [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/ssl-information-center/transitioning-to-sha-256.html) | [This Dude](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)